# Create a N-D matrix in Eigen (C++ Library)

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen

How could we create a `T(n, m, k)` matrix like MATLAB using Eigen in c++?
It creates k matrices which are n*m.

Answer (score 0):

Include the tensor module:

```
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>
```

Declare it like this:

```
Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> epsilon(3,3,3);
```

More info: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Tensor_support

Comment: How could I add Tensor to Eigen library? I haven't found any link to download Tensor part.

Comment: It's already there, just in the unsupported folder, i.e. `Eigen/../unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor`. If you unzip a new copy of Eigen, you'll see it.

Comment: it doesn't work! A lot of errors while using Tensor in Eigen...
Is there any other solution instead?

Comment: Are you using C++ 11? Check out the requirements section on the link above.

Comment: You can also try this: https://github.com/ndarray/ndarray (never tried it myself, just found it on Google)